# Redirect entire command including result to .txt file

Tags: batch-file

```
>%DT%.TXT 2>&1 (
xcopy E:\OUTSIDE\XFORM\%FN%.frm D:\OUTSIDE\XFORM /y
xcopy E:\OUTSIDE\XFORM\%FN%.fsl D:\OUTSIDE\XFORM /y
xcopy E:\OUTSIDE\XIMAGE\%FN%.img D:\OUTSIDE\XFORM /y
)
```

The code above is a sample of the lines I need redirected to a text file. This currently works with the exception that it only shows where the file is being copied from and how many files are being copied.

I need to be able to redirect the entire line so I can see where the files are being copied to as well for control purposes. Not entirely sure this is even possible via batch. Sadly it's my only option at this time.

Comment: Add a `/f` switch to the `xcopy` command

Comment: That worked! Thanks a ton, unfortunately it brought up another issue....

Anytime the section of code above is called it writes over whats currently in the txt file instead of appending to it.

Comment: And I solved it myself, I'm a bone head and was using single > instead of double to append...

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I offer two simple batch solutions.

The first one is using parameter `/F` as suggested by [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd):

```
>>%DT%.TXT 2>&1 (
    xcopy E:\OUTSIDE\XFORM\%FN%.frm D:\OUTSIDE\XFORM /F /I /Y
    xcopy E:\OUTSIDE\XFORM\%FN%.fsl D:\OUTSIDE\XFORM /F /I /Y
    xcopy E:\OUTSIDE\XIMAGE\%FN%.img D:\OUTSIDE\XFORM /F /I /Y
)
```

The help of command **xcopy** can be read by running in a command prompt window `xcopy /?` which explains parameter `/I` as well - `D:\OUTSIDE\XFORM` should be interpreted as destination folder to be created automatically if not already existing.

The second one is echoing the source and destination before making the copy:

```
>>%DT%.TXT 2>&1 (
    echo Copying E:\OUTSIDE\XFORM\%FN%.frm to D:\OUTSIDE\XFORM
    xcopy E:\OUTSIDE\XFORM\%FN%.frm D:\OUTSIDE\XFORM /I /Y
    echo Copying E:\OUTSIDE\XFORM\%FN%.fsl to D:\OUTSIDE\XFORM
    xcopy E:\OUTSIDE\XFORM\%FN%.fsl D:\OUTSIDE\XFORM /I /Y
    echo Copying E:\OUTSIDE\XFORM\%FN%.img to D:\OUTSIDE\XFORM
    xcopy E:\OUTSIDE\XIMAGE\%FN%.img D:\OUTSIDE\XFORM /I /Y
)
```